# AWS KMS InvalidSignatureException when usign correct signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, cryptography, rsa, aws-cli, amazon-kms

The sequence of commands I am running is:

```bash
$ aws kms sign --key-id 29245e92-1763-4369-871b-d8646e23c40a --message "Hello world!" --signing-algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256
{
    "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:445875827267:key/29245e92-1763-4369-871b-d8646e23c40a",
    "Signature": "T8eYRCTFuigdnHCuYytLscu9EGcdg9UJupPwVB1F3vEENgnkQR37ZPbn5nPr6CTahX+AXTXLFXf8trxRHKoy8997vfuyMaH3RwhFYBDJiAYdJQeBWSyqw5TIwOAnjAYNwJHuX2N8RY2+yKA1vHARNtOiHUesrc/+6eMbaf+ZTJEhY3aIuThW3cjCjnWSoaC44NIMuXfTOVMBhfoKuMW+IZSjH4cCxgj1MaR2sumnCwRW6irTRQOo/NBaxV/8NUWO9RMavDyFpeoxotNGFK0MNhbia4wkady5Dw0orWZSMI30kly66I5ubu+wVgX14GLIiSZofd9Y7RzHmvxL2MTxiQ==",
    "SigningAlgorithm": "RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256"
}

$ aws kms verify --key-id 29245e92-1763-4369-871b-d8646e23c40a --message "Hello world!" --signature T8eYRCTFuigdnHCuYytLscu9EGcdg9UJupPwVB1F3vEENgnkQR37ZPbn5nPr6CTahX+AXTXLFXf8trxRHKoy8997vfuyMaH3RwhFYBDJiAYdJQeBWSyqw5TIwOAnjAYNwJHuX2N8RY2+yKA1vHARNtOiHUesrc/+6eMbaf+ZTJEhY3aIuThW3cjCjnWSoaC44NIMuXfTOVMBhfoKuMW+IZSjH4cCxgj1MaR2sumnCwRW6irTRQOo/NBaxV/8NUWO9RMavDyFpeoxotNGFK0MNhbia4wkady5Dw0orWZSMI30kly66I5ubu+wVgX14GLIiSZofd9Y7RzHmvxL2MTxiQ== --signing-algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256

An error occurred (KMSInvalidSignatureException) when calling the Verify operation:
```

Surely this should work? What am I missing here?

Comment: The CLI expects the raw signature for verify, so you'll need to decode it with `echo T8...xiQ== | base64 --decode > raw_signature.sig` then use `--signature fileb://raw_signature.sig` to load the raw signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved from Anon's Comment except need to use `fileb://` instead:
e.g.

```bash
$aws kms verify --key-id 29245e92-1763-4369-871b-d8646e23c40a --message "Hello world!" --signature fileb://raw.sig --signing-algorithm RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256
{
    "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:445875827267:key/29245e92-1763-4369-871b-d8646e23c40a",
    "SignatureValid": true,
    "SigningAlgorithm": "RSASSA_PSS_SHA_256"
}
```